# Regex accepting string that meets "('a'*N - 'b'*M)%3 = 0" requirement

Tags: regex

going further with the subject, I have been trying to write a regex which:
"from an alphabet of {a,b} accepts the string only if it's occurences of 'a' minus occurences of 'b' can be divided by 3." 
Could someone please help me dealing with this? I know that I should give ANY input of my own to help solving this problem but I have no clue whatsoever.

Maybe only that it probably should start with (aaa) as a base an then expand further with next "pairs" of 'a's and 'b's but I dont know how to make it expand like "(aaa)aaabbb" and not like "(aaa)ababab".

Comment: I am not sure you can do this with regex alone...

Comment: it seems like you could use a regex to get the counts, but will need further development to do the division/modular arithmetic

Comment: This is indeed regular language, since you can easily [implement an FSM](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom7/211/fsm/4f.gif) for it: you start with an accepting state and have two other, non-accepting states. They’re arranged in a circle. `a` transitions go in one direction, `b` transitions in the opposite direction.

Comment: I don’t really understand your last statement. What do you mean by expanding it “like `(aaa)aaabbb`” but “not like `(aaa)ababab`”?

Comment: ok: "(aaa)aaabbb" and "(aaa)ababab" *both* have six a's and three b's. so *both* satisfy your original stated goal. (it's simple counting, nothing to do with regex).  You then say those strings differ in some way, which 1) contradicts your previous statement and 2) which way they differ is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Count-based regex problems are easiest to represent using a Finite State Automata, and reduce it to a single pattern.

With three nodes, one for each modular value; Define the transitions as what happens to the modular value when `a` or `b` are processed.

[image]

Then collapse one node, by replacing each path through the node by single transitions.

- `0->2->0` → `0->0` (`ba`)
- `0->2->1` → `0->1` (`bb`)
- `1->2->0` → `1->0` (`aa`)
- `1->2->1` → `1->1` (`ab`)

[image]

Repeat for another node.

- `0->1(->1)*->0` → `0->0` (`(a|bb)(ab)*(b|aa)`)

[image]

The final pattern is: `(ba|(a|bb)(ab)*(b|aa))*`

Comment: @RicardoBranco https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/lectures/lect_08.pdf